# How does the Gutenberg mobile/tablet/desktop preview work with media queries?

Tags: block-editor

I am building a block which has different layouts for mobile and desktop.
As far as I understand CSS media queries, they work when the viewport is resized.

[image]

The preview feature in Gutenberg doesn't actually resize the viewport, it just reduces the width of the container containing the blocks.

I saw that the core Gutenberg block "Gallery" changes its layout when switched between desktop and mobile preview modes. I was wondering how that works? I checked the source code and even checked the Dev tools to detect any addition/removal of CSS classes but couldn't find any.

Can someone shed some light please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I investigated the states set using React Dev Tools and found the preview modes are set under the `deviceType` key. Went through the Gutenberg source and came across the `__experimentalGetPreviewDeviceType` function.

```
/**
 * Returns the current deviceType.
 */
const { deviceType } = useSelect( select => {
    const { __experimentalGetPreviewDeviceType } = select( 'core/edit-post' );

    return {
        deviceType: __experimentalGetPreviewDeviceType(),
    }
}, [] );
```

I'm using this to conditionally set the CSS classes. Worked for me and I hope the Gallery block is doing the same way.